# Reactjs How to use if... else before render block

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      check1 : false,
      check2 : false,
      checktext : ""
      .
      .
      }

oncheck=(e)=>
{
  this.setState({ check1 : !this.state.check1})
}
oncheck2=(e)=>
{
  this.setState({ check2 : !this.state.check2})
}

 render() {
      if( this.state.check1 === true) {
        this.state.checktext= "Marked true";
      }
      else if(this.state.check1 === false)
      {
        this.state.checktext= "Marked false";
      }
      .
      .
      .
      return (
      .
      . 
      .
       <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.check1} onChange={this.oncheck}/> <br />
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.check2} onChange={this.oncheck2}/> <br />
      <p> Text {this.state.checktext}  </p>
```

This code working but console error Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()  react/no-direct-mutation-state. How to use if else before render block. Thank you.

Comment: How many checks do you have?

Comment: Never mutate the state directly. Use `this.setState({YOUR_NEW_STATE})`

Comment: Don't mutate state inside `render`

Comment: Sorry edit the code.

Comment: There are several issues above (modifying state in `render`, modifying state directly rather than via `setState`, using `=== true` and `=== false` which is rarely appropriate). But in comments you've said each time that that wasn't the problem. We can't help you without a more complete example. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need state to achieve what you are doing just use a variable like

```
 render() {
 var checktext=""
      if( this.state.check1 === true) {
        checktext= "Marked true";
      }
      else if(this.state.check1 === false)
      {
        checktext= "Marked false";
      }
```

and use it like

`<p> Text {checktext}  </p>`

Comment: personally I dont think this is the recommended way as he has `checktext` in the `state` object. It's very messy from the way i see it

Comment: @Isaac checktext has no use being in the state, it is not something that is causing/has to cause the render , rather it is the checkbox that is responsible, this is the correct way, you should not put unnecessary things in state that are not not actually the state of the application. React state is definitely overused by most.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
  if(this.state.check1 === true) {
    this.setState({
      checktext= "Marked true";
    });
  }
```

Please see docs for more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `method` inside the `render()` and make the validation check inside that method.

For e.g. :

```
render(){
     this.doValidation();
     ....
```

Inside `doValidation()`, you can check for the validation.

```
 doValidation(){ 
     if( this.state.check1 === true) {
         this.setState({check5: "Marked true"}); 
     } else if (this.state.check1 === false) {
         this.setState({check5: "Marked false"}); 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fine tuning @supra28 answer, if var check1 can have only true or false then you can use the below code since it is good to avoid if condition at possible places as best practice.

```
render() {
   var checktext="";
   checktext = (this.state.check1 === true) ? "Marked true" : "Marked false";
}
```